# How to avoid memory leaks during periodical AJAX requests on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, memory-management, mootools

I've developed a webpage showing some statistics.
These statistics are refreshed periodically by AJAX requests using mootools 1.4.5.

Here ist the basic code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var statisticRequest = new Request.HTML({
      url: theURL,
      noCache: true,
      onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {
         $(responseTree[0]).replaces($('statisticContainer'))
      }
   })

   function getCurrentStatistics() {
      statisticRequest.get()
   }

   window.addEvent('domready', function(){
      getCurrentStatistics.periodical(2000)
   });
</script>
```

On FF all works fine but the IE9 continuously allocates memory until the machine is nearly freezed.
It looks like the garbage collector didn't remove the old DOM elements.

Using [sIEve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/), I can see the increasing number of DOM elememts and the resulting memory usage.

What can I do to force the IE to remove the unused elements?

**Edit:**

Using `destroy()` as shown below will slow down the memory consumption but will not stop it completely. Removing `Request.HTML` had no further effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var statisticRequest = new Request({
        url: theURL,
        noCache: true,
        onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {
            var newStatistic = Elements.from(responseText)
            var oldStatistic = $('statisticContainer')
            newStatistic.replaces(oldStatistic)
            oldStatistic.destroy()
        }
    })

    function getCurrentStatistics() {
        statisticRequest.get()
    }

    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        getCurrentStatistics.periodical(2000)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. look at the code for this:

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L743-747

it will just replace it in the dom. it won't really do much in terms of GC - the old element still 'exists' - in case you want to re-attach it.

http://jsfiddle.net/rE3JH/

```
var foo = document.id('foo');
new Element('div').replaces(foo);
console.log(foo); // still an element, though not in the dom
```

call `foo.destroy();` to properly GC - see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L802-807

alternatively, update the parent of `staticContainer` - applying a change to innerHTML direct. also, keep in mind `.empty()` will `dispose` child nodes and not `destroy` them - for periodical stuff like yours, you need to be thorough as it can avalanche over time.

Comment: `destroy()` does not seem to work. Both sIEve and the Windows TaskManager still showing continuously growing memory consumption.

Comment: The process of memory consumtion is much slower than before, so `destroy()` seems to have an effect. What could be other sources for a memory leak in my code? Maybee `Request.HTML` itselfs?

Comment: i cannot comment unless i see your code. there have been some issues posted about Ie memory leaks in the `Element` constructor - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2300. also read: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2225 to do with memory leaks in `removeChild` - I don't have any answers - you can talk to ibolmo on irc who has looked into that in more details. my advice here would be, drop Request.HTML as that does too much extra parsing - instead, go with normal Request and use the response.text to update the innerHTML of the target div. should fix your issues.

Comment: Element.destroy() has issues too, this JSFiddle shows the fault http://jsfiddle.net/5UrtK/

Comment: that's not exactly an unknown issue but storage is there by design... Let me repeat: **AVOID USE OF REQUEST.HTML IN LONG POLLING PERSISTENT APPS**. Basically, Element storage is behind a closure and is setup as soon as a selector accesses an element or a collection. Using Request.HTML and working on element level will create storage and assign a uid to each element passed (the key in the Storage object). Using pure `Request` will not as there is no element access. SO, fine unless you use a selector to do something on the table after. check this: http://jsfiddle.net/5UrtK/2/

Comment: and you can use event delegation on the parent to AVOID attaching events to the table elements. sorted. smaller footprint by removal of multiple event handlers. think of all the orphaned functions that stay in the storage (yes, thats where they go), processing time of creating and assigning and saving references to functions all around.

Comment: also, keep state. don't go to dom and update it for every reply. if nothing has changed, either don't send a reply, send a 302 or compare reply with previous reply and update dom on changes alone.

Comment: @Dimitar - Thanks for the info, I raised this on github 2 weeks ago, https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2308 but noone has commented on it, I even put a workaround on it, should i remove/close it

Comment: this looks like old code, you reference `element.uid` which was deprecated in `1.4.4` in favour of `Slick.uidOf(element)` (API) or `element.uniqueNumber` internally. in any case, destroy will apply `clean`, other ways to remove items will not. I'd comment on your issue though i'd have to spend time investigating it more (which I don't have right now)

Comment: I added my current code above. Any new ideas? Does it make sense to use `element.set('html', newHtml)`?

Comment: totally. new Elements will go through UID creation again. just output what you get as string - and ONLY if its different from the previous one.

Comment: Ok! I thought I have to destroy the old elements before setting the new htlm but with `$('hotlineStatisticContainer').set('html', responseText)` the memory consumption looks stable on IE9. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I've been playing about with this for a while.  I think you're better to use something like mootools.  It's well tested and is pretty small.  It also gives you lots of extra features that are all cross browser compatible and don't need extensve testing.

I've run the following code for over two hours with no memory leaks. Hope it helps either the questioner or someone else searching stack overflow:  First the index.html file:

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                <title>Untitled Document</title>
                <style>
                img.slide{
                    border:1px solid black;
                }
                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools/mootoolsCore.js">
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools/mootoolsMore.js">
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

        function data(){
            this.who="alan";
            this.pageHolder=1;
            this.lastPage = 4;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        var newData = new data();

        function changePage(newData,dirn){
            newData.dirn = dirn;
            saveData(newData);
        }

        function saveData(newData) {
            //alert("reached save data");
            var dataJSON = JSON.encode (newData);
            var request = new Request.JSON({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'forwardDataJson.php',
                data: {
                    json: dataJSON
                    },
                onComplete: function(jsonObj) {
                    newData.pageHolder = jsonObj.pageHolder;
                    newData.count = jsonObj.count;
                    $("picHolder").set('html','<img class="slide" src ="OpeningSlide/Slide'+jsonObj.pageHolder+'.jpg"/>');
                    $("alertBox").set('html',jsonObj.alertGiven);
                    $("countme").set('html',jsonObj.count);

                }
            }).send();
        };
        function getCurrentStatistics() {
              saveData(newData);
           }

           window.addEvent('domready', function(){
              getCurrentStatistics.periodical(2000)
           });

        </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="alertBox"></div>
                <button  type="button" onmousedown="changePage(newData,'backward')"/>backward</button>
                <button  type="button" onmousedown="changePage(newData,'forward')">forward</button>

                <div id="picHolder"><img class="slide" src ="OpeningSlide/Slide1.jpg"/></div>
                <div id="countme">0</div>

            </body>
        </html>
```

This looks for a series of images (Slide1.jpg, Slid2.jpg etc) and then displays them on the page.  It checks every two seconds for a new bit of info and gets a counter number. Clicking forward or back makes the slides run through every 2 seconds.  Not very exciting but it demonstrates the princilple of using AJAX and a server poll with Mootools.

You also need a server side script. Which in this case is:

```
        <?php
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $test = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
        }else{
            $test = $_POST['json'];
        }
        $obj = json_decode($test);

        $direction = $obj->{'dirn'};
        $counter = $obj->{'count'};
        ++$counter;
        $obj->{'count'} = $counter;
        switch ($direction) {
            case "forward":
                if($obj->{'pageHolder'} < $obj->{'lastPage'}){
                    ++$obj->{'pageHolder'} ;
                }
                break;
            case "backward":
                if($obj->{'pageHolder'} >1){
                    --$obj->{'pageHolder'} ;
                }
                break;

        }


        $reply = json_encode($obj);

        echo $reply;
        ?>
```

You'll notice that I've used JSON for passing an object to and from the server.  This is just for ease of coding.  If you've never used it before it's the way to go (in my opinion at least) since it's straightforward to use once you get your head around it.

This example should work as is.  You simply need a directory called OpeningSlide which should contain your jpg slides/images and of course the mootools libs.

Hope this helps

Incidently if you're wondering about the first few lines of the php code it's there to sort out issues with JSON and magic quotes.  It adjusts for magic quotes being on or off at the server.  You can remove it if you know your server setting.